# SystemDrawing.SystemColors.GradientInactiveCaption how to change in window?

Tags: vb.net, system.drawing.color

I have a program which used "SystemDrawing.SystemColors.GradientInactiveCaption" to get machine default color.
Tried "https://winaero.com/blog/change-color-of-inactive-title-bars-in-windows-10/" to change the color of my windows, unfortunately the value do not changed. 
Is anyone have ideas on this?

Many thanks!

Comment: That setting got harder to change with every new Windows release.  Afaik the applet is completely gone for Win10.  You can change it with Regedit.exe, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors key.  Log out and log back in to ensure the change is effective for all windows.  If that doesn't work then ask at superuser.com

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant! It is useful and now I knew that the settings storing place!